# The PhantomJS executable could not be found on the current PATH. To be resolved

Tags: phantomjs

I am getting following error message 
`The PhantomJS executable could not be found on the current PATH.` from the compiler when I am building my project.

Is there any solution existing for it?

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: When trying to
  
const WebDriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const driver = new WebDriver.Builder()
.withCapabilities(
  WebDriver.Capabilities.phantomjs()
).build()

it trows error

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, while calling the phantomJS driver instance, you need to pass a variable **executable_path**

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = '/home/someLocation/phantomJS')
```

This solved it for me